# Mingw-w64, what's the purpose of libgcc_s_seh.dll?

Tags: mingw-w64

Libraries built with Mingw-w64 require those dll:

```
libwinpthread-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
```

I wonder what's up with that, what each dll does? Especially libgcc_s_seh, is that structured exception handling? I thought mingw couldn't work with seh.

Why mingw requires to always bring those dll with your exe?

I wonder if I'm just wasting my time by not just using visual studio as a windows compiler. It's so bloated though, 9 gb for installation.

Comment: You can build a self-contained executable by using static linking (i.e. then you do not need to transport these DLLs). It just defaults to the DLL mode, presumably to save on disk space in the case of there being multiple executables.

Answer (score 8):

> Especially libgcc_s_seh, is that structured exception handling? I thought mingw couldn't work with seh.

Newer versions of GCC (4.8+ if I'm correct) should support SEH on MinGW.

> I wonder what's up with that, what each dll does?

They provide the runtime and standard library.

- **libwinpthread**: PThreads implementation on Windows (Threading)
- **libstdc++**: C++ Standard Library (C/C++ library functions etc.)
- **libgcc_s_seh**: Exception handling (SEH)

> Why mingw requires to always bring those dll with your exe?

Because your program uses them. If you write a program without threads, standard library and exception and any OS interaction you wont need them.

These DLL's bring everything you need to run your program. Btw. this is *not* a MinGW only thing, and happens on other systems / compilers too. Often you just don't note this because the OS already ships the libraries, eg. MSVC libraries are very likely on a Windows machine. *Dynamic linking* always requires some sort of library files, that are `.dll` on Windows and `.so` on Linux.

If you have it available on your system use `ldd <your application>` to see what libraries are dynamically linked.

You can install these MinGW libraries into the system libraries or somewhere where the OS can find it. This enables your programs to use it and you no longer have to ship it with every application (what avoids duplication).

On the other side another option is to *static* link them. Unlike *dynamic* linking, you don't need any DLL; on the downside is a increase of you applications size (as now the three libraries are baked into the exe now).

> I wonder if I'm just wasting my time by not just using visual studio as a windows compiler.

This depends on your situation. But probably my answer will give you some more insight.

Comment: Technically it should be possible to use kernel32.dll and user32.dll directly for threading and seh. I'm wondering why mingw isn't smart enough to do that. Feels so wasteful. Can I get some links on those dll, on how they work? Maybe the source code?

Comment: No, because MinGW uses POSIX Threads (PThreads) and the GCC Exception model, not the Windows ones; Windows on the other hand doesn't support these. That's why you can't use the those two Windows DLL's. MinGW provides a GNU System on Windows and as such it follows the GNU / POSIX implementation.

Comment: You can find the source code on the [mingw-w64 website](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/start). I think most of (if not all) code is available through their [repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/master/tree/). Maybe you can find some more information on the upstream [GNU GCC Website](https://gcc.gnu.org/).