# Insight On Files Needed to Share Executables Made On Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

This is a fairly general question regarding the Code::Blocks IDE, more specifically, version 20.03. It is fairly simple to create a console application of any kind using this IDE for some purpose. However, based on my experiences, it requires a little more effort to run this file on its own, outside the building environment of the IDE. A solution to this, which can be found online, is adding to Windows environment variables, the path to three DLL files, which come with the software when installed. They are titled as follows:

```
libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
```

I would simply like to know why these files are required in specific and perhaps what the code they house does, purely for understanding purposes.

Comment: Those are dependencies of the MinGW compiler, not related directly to Code::Blocks.

Comment: I understand, that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate (the top answer covers all three) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728353

Comment: I understand. That is my mistake, thank you for your bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Did that link answer your question?

Comment: It helped me better understand the reasoning behind why these are needed and this affecting the MinGW compiler as a whole, not this IDE. However, I will leave the question for any other answers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: A related question (not really a duplicate, but someone finding this question in the future might be interested): [MinGW .exe requires a few gcc dll's regardless of the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138635)